# How to split mysql dump file into smaller chunks and concatenate after

Tags: mysql, split, concatenation, migration, openedx

Good day! I am having a problem regarding the migration of our database. I will explain it into much detail as I can.

I am using an [OpenEdx Platform](https://openedx.org/) and we are on the process of migrating our mongoDB and mysqlDB.

The instructions based on the [documentation](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/COMM/pages/3249438723/How+to+migrate+from+a+native+deployment+to+a+tutor+deployment+of+the+Open+edX+platform) into restoring it unto the new instance is as follows:

```
By default in Tutor, the name of the edx-platform service database is openedx while it’s called edxapp in the native installation:

(Recommended) Edit your MySQL dump file:
```

1. Add `DROP DATABASE openedx;` to the SQL file above the `CREATE DATABASE` line.
2. Change `CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/` **edxapp** `/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;` to `CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/` **openedx** `/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;`
3. Change `USE edxapp;` to `USE openedx;`

But the problem is, our database is too big.
I can't even edit the dump file as it takes too long to load. How can I split it? And if I do split it, how can I concatenate it again so that I can now perform the restoration process?

I tried the second option based on the [documentation](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/COMM/pages/3249438723/How+to+migrate+from+a+native+deployment+to+a+tutor+deployment+of+the+Open+edX+platform) but now, I am suffering some of its consequences.

Comment: By the way, I am using a remote server regarding this platform (Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

Use "--compress" option with "mysqldump": This option compresses the data as it is being dumped, which reduces the size of the resulting dump file. Use same "--compress" when restoring the database.

Use "--hex-blob" option with "mysqldump": This option causes mysqldump to dump binary data in hexadecimal format. This can be useful when dumping binary data such as images or files. Use "--hex-blob" when restoring the database.

Comment: This may compress the file, but I do need to edit the file after by adding a DROP DATABASE openedx; to the SQL file above the CREATE DATABASE line.

Comment: What's the file size? Did you try Sublime or Vim?